# critical markup in org-mode or emacs?

Tags: org-mode, writing

*Is there support for [Critical Markdown](http://criticmarkup.com/users-guide.php) in org-mode or in Emacs text editing in general?*

I am interested in MSWord style [track-changes in plain text](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/6864), and learned that [Critical Markdown](http://criticmarkup.com/users-guide.php) fits the bill. On their website, they listed a number of supporting editors such as a BBEdit Plugin and a Sublime Text Plugin.

Is there a similar mode in Emacs for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I know of at least criticmarkup modes. Here are the links:
https://github.com/joostkremers/criticmarkup-emacs
https://github.com/syohex/criticmarkup-emacs